# Behavior of echo command with pipe operator on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wanted to make a batch file to print the value of a variable by passing the name of variable through the command line argument ex.

```
print.bat username
```

the content of print.bat are

```
@echo off
setlocal
set v=%%%1%%%
echo | echo %v%
```

Although the script is working perfectly but I still don't understand the working of

```
echo | echo %v%
```

My understanding of the pipes is that the output of first command (i.e. command at the left side of pipe operator) is passed to the second command (i.e. the command to the right of pipe operator) so according to this the correct way should have been `echo %v% | echo` (which does not work).

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Echo does not read standard input.  Regardless, why do you think you need pipe an empty echo to another echo command?  Maybe you are trying to do: `echo.&echo %v%` ??

Comment: @Squashman - it seems to be acting like `call`, which is incredibly strange since I wouldn't expect `echo` to accept piped input either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> set v=%%%1%%%
> ```

`%1` is the first argument passed on the command line, in your example `username`. The `%%` are then halved when parsing the line, and the lone `%` at the end is discarded, leaving `v` set to `%username%`.

> ```
> echo | echo %v%
> ```

`echo %v%` is parsed as `echo %username%`, but the pipe forces it to execute in a second instance of the interpreter, where it undergoes another round of parsing which expands `%username%` to the value of the `username` environment variable.

> the correct way should have been `echo %v% | echo` (which does not work)

That does not and cannot work since `echo` does not use the standard input stream. The output of the first `echo %v%` command is discarded, and the second `echo` finds no command line arguments, so it prints the usual `ECHO is on`.

Key point here is that the first `echo` in `echo | echo %v%` is not actually used as an `echo`. Its only role is to allow the pipe, which in turn causes the re-parsing of the second `echo` command. For example `type nul | echo %v%` would work just the same.

However, this could be accomplished more cheaply without unnecessary piping, using `call`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "v=%%%1%%"
call echo %v%
```